# NSLeftTextMovement and NSRightTextMovement

Tags: macos, appkit

On what action do the NSTextEndEditing notifications contain NSLeftTextMovement & NSRightTextMovement? I was trying to catch left/right/up/down key press inside a text field, but the NSTextMovement key value is always either Tab/BackTab or Return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work to catch arrow key presses in a text field.

The `NSTextDidEndEditingNotification` is only sent when focus leaves the field editor. So, `NSLeftTextMovement` would only be used if/when a press of the left arrow press actually caused focus to leave the field. That's not something that normally happens. I don't know if it might happen when using a matrix of text fields or an `NSForm`. One could arrange to use a custom field editor and have that end editing on an arrow key press, too, I suppose.